# Discord.py, making a server lockdown command. Not working as intended

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm making a command that would update the permissions for every channel I ask it to. However I'm having issues with getting all the channels to change their perms. It updated the channel the command is executed in, but none of the others. I'm assuming this is because Context is NOT what I should be using in this command. Here is my code:

```
@zip.command(aliases=['sd'])
@commands.has_role('Mods')
async def shutdown(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    intro = zip.get_channel(631272968093433856)
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
    suggestions = zip.get_channel(631881727064801280)
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
    general = zip.get_channel(630907637919121420)
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
    memes = zip.get_channel(631273005489586176)
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
    wholesome_me = zip.get_channel(631273030265602090)
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
    music_d = zip.get_channel(631273090260926475)
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
    no_mic = zip.get_channel(631273262047035413)
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
    bot_com = zip.get_channel(631273294170947605)
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
    await ctx.send("**SERVER HAS BEEN LOCKED DOWN**")
```

I also have an a unshutdown command that would reset them all to None. It's formatted the same way

There are no errors in the console, the code runs but doesn't work as intended. Again I think it's the ctx part of it, but I would love some help.

Many thanks for taking the time to read this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting permissions for `ctx.channel` each time.  Instead, set them for the channel objects you're getting:

```
intro = zip.get_channel(631272968093433856)
await intro.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
...
```

Comment: Sorry, unfortunatley I get an error with your solution:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_permissions'
`
Edit: Scratch that, it was an error on my part. Works fine now. Thanks!